# Dynamically fusion rows cells with same values in Excel

Tags: excel

In a datasheet with automatic filters, I have this (values and columns names are for example) :

```
Continent      Country      City        Street
----------------------------------------------------------
Asia           Vietnam      Hanoi       egdsqgdfgdsfg
Asia           Vietnam      Hanoi       fhfdghdfdh
Asia           Vietnam      Hanoi       dfhdfhfdhfdhfdhfdh
Asia           Vietnam      Saigon      ggdsfgfdsdgsdfgdf
Asia           Vietnam      Hue         qsdfqsfqsdf
Asia           China        Beijing     qegfqsddfgdf
Asia           China        Canton      sdgsdfgsdgsdg
Asia           China        Canton      tjgjfgj
Asia           China        Canton      tzeryrty
Asia           Japan        Tokyo       ertsegsgsdfdg
Asia           Japan        Kyoto       qegdgdfgdfgdf
Asia           Japan        Sapporo     gsdgfdgsgsdfgf
Europa         France       Paris       qfqsdfdsqfgsdfgsg
Europa         France       Toulon      qgrhrgqzfqzetzeqrr
Europa         France       Lyon        pàjhçuhàçuh
Europa         Italy        Rome        qrgfqegfgdfg
Europa         Italy        Rome        qergqegsdfgsdfgdsg
```

I would like this to be displayed like this, with rows fusionned dynamically if filters changes

```
Continent      Country      City        Street
    ----------------------------------------------------------
                                            egdsqgdfgdsfg
                                Hanoi       fhfdghdfdh
                   Vietnam                  dfhdfhfdhfdhfdhfdh
                                Saigon      ggdsfgfdsdgsdfgdf
                                Hue         qsdfqsfqsdf
                   ---
    Asia                        Beijing     qegfqsddfgdf
                   China                    sdgsdfgsdgsdg
                                Canton      tjgjfgj
                                            tzeryrty
                   ---
                                Tokyo       ertsegsgsdfdg
                   Japan        Kyoto       qegdgdfgdfgdf
                                Sapporo     gsdgfdgsgsdfgf
    ---
                                Paris       qfqsdfdsqfgsdfgsg
                   France       Toulon      qgrhrgqzfqzetzeqrr
    Europa                      Lyon        pàjhçuhàçuh
                   Italy        Rome        qrgfqegfgdfg
                                            qergqegsdfgsdfgdsg
```

Is macro mandatory for this ?

I don't want to merge values in Street column. I want to keep all lines. I just want to work on the first column display to avoid having long series of same values.

Comment: Do you need to change the data?  Or is this just for display/filter/browsing purposes?

Comment: I will need to change or add data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also setup a PivotTable - this would look like this:

[image]

Just go to "insert->pivottable" and select your given data as input and create the pivottable as new worksheet ;)

Put all field in the "rows" section, remove any subsum or sum calculations.

Because you don't have any values to sum up, you should just hide those columns, to get a clear view.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. All field in "rows" section made it. I have some issues about formating but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Function.
You can do it like this:

```
=IF(MATCH(Tabelle1!A1;(Tabelle1!A:A);0)=ROW();Tabelle1!A1;"")
```

Insert this Formula in a other Sheet.